# How to check if Hyper-V is compatible with a particular NIC (Killer E2200 NIC)?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, network-adapter, hyper-v

I'm making a PC and the motherboard I've picked out has on-board Ethernet using a Killer E2200 NIC. I plan on using Microsoft Hyper-V but I understand that it performs a number of lower level operations to allow for guests to connect to the network.

- How can I check if Hyper-V and this particular NIC are compatible? What features or settings do I need to check exist on both to ensure they are compatible?
- Has anyone on here used Hyper-V and this particular NIC, and if so, did it work?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be compatible.  A network card is a network card.  You provide the drivers and it simply works.

Comment: I don't know, but given that Hyper-V installs it's own networking drivers I wanted to check.